# Call a function and provide output in a matrix

Tags: r, function, matrix, call

I have a function in R which I call

```
RS1 = t(cbind(Data[,18], Data[,20]))
RS2 = t(cbind(Data[,19], Data[,21]))
p = t(Data[23:24])

rand_x <- function (p, x) {
  n.goods <- dim (p)[1]
  n.obs   <- dim (p)[2]
  xRC = NaN*matrix(1, n.goods, n.obs)
  for(i in 1:n.obs) {
    xRC[1,i] <- RS1[1,i] + RS1[2,i]
    xRC[2,i] <- RS2[1,i] + RS2[2,i]
  }
  result <- xRC
  return(result)
}
```

This function by having these two inputs generates a vector (2x50) with some random numbers. I want to call this function rand_x 1000 times and derive 1000 matrices and then bind the results in a final matrix. I have tried to create a loop to sort this problem but I am still struggling. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post you loop code

Comment: rand_x <- function (p, x) {

n.goods <- 2; n.obs <- 50;

RS1 = t(cbind(Data[,18], Data[,20]));
RS2 = t(cbind(Data[,19], Data[,21]));


xRC = NaN*matrix(1, n.goods, n.obs);


  for(i in 1:n.obs){
           xRC[1,i] <- RS1[1,i] + RS1[2,i];
           xRC[2,i] <- RS2[1,i] + RS2[2,i];
         }

result <- xRC

return(result)
}

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to add each element of column 18 to 20 (that is what your code does), try using rowSums().

Try:

```
xRC <- rbind(
  rowSums (Data [, c(18, 20)])
  rowSums (Data [, c(19, 21)])
)
```

The output will be a matrix.

I do not see, where randomness appears in your function though. If you just want a 2x50 matrix with random numbers you may want to use:

```
xRC <- matrix (rnorm(50*2), 2)  # for standard-normal generated numbers
xRC <- matrix (sample(1:100, replace = T, size = 100), 2)  # for numbers between 1 and 100, uniformly distributed
```

To do this 1000 times, try:

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
  rbind(xRC,
    rowSums (Data [, c(18, 20)])
    rowSums (Data [, c(19, 21)])
  )
}
# or if you just want to generate random numbers, performance is way faster when you use:
xRC <- matrix(rnorm(1000 * 2 * 50), ncol = 50)
```